# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in host code with OpenCL buffers

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, buffer, opencl

I'm trying to code an host that send parameters to a core function.
I got a problem with the dimension of the parameters, I define these vectors:

```
    std::vector<char, aligned_allocator<char>> string(maxstring);
    std::vector<char, aligned_allocator<char>> pattern(maxseq);
    std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> vStringdim(DIM);
    std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> vSeqdim(DIM);
    std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> vOcc(DIM);
    std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> vPi(piDIM * DIM);
```

With constant dimension:

```
#define DIM 50           
#define maxseq 256         
#define maxstring 2048 
#define piDIM 257
```

Then I pass them to a function, which takes as arguments

```
                cl::CommandQueue &q,
                cl::Kernel &kernel,
                std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> &vStringdim,
                std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> &vSeqdim,
                std::vector<char, aligned_allocator<char>> &vString,
                std::vector<char, aligned_allocator<char>> &vSeq,
                std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> &vPi,
                std::vector<int, aligned_allocator<int>> &vOcc)
{
```

And creates the buffers in OpenCL

```
 OCL_CHECK(err,
              cl::Buffer buffer_stringdim(context,

                                          CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR |
                                              CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                          sizeof(int) * DIM,
                                          vStringdim.data(),
                                          &err));
    OCL_CHECK(err,
              cl::Buffer buffer_seqdim(context,

                                       CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR |
                                           CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                       sizeof(int) * DIM,
                                       vSeqdim.data(),
                                       &err));

    OCL_CHECK(err,
              cl::Buffer buffer_string(context,

                                       CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR |
                                           CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                       sizeof(char) * maxstring,
                                       vString.data(),
                                       &err));

    OCL_CHECK(err,
              cl::Buffer buffer_seq(context,

                                    CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR |
                                        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                    sizeof(char) * maxseq,
                                    vSeq.data(),
                                    &err));
    OCL_CHECK(err,
              cl::Buffer buffer_pi(context,

                                   CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR |
                                       CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                   sizeof(int) * piDIM * DIM,
                                   vPi.data(),
                                   &err));

    OCL_CHECK(err,
              cl::Buffer buffer_occ(context,

                                    CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR |
                                        CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
                                    sizeof(int) * DIM,
                                    vOcc.data(),
                                    &err));
```

And I call the kernel, which take the arguments like these and perform some operations:

```
void kmp(int *occ, int *stringdim, int *seqdim, char *seq, char *string, int *pi)
```

With the previous parameters declared it works fine and actually it return the right result without exceptions. But using these parameters:

```
#define DIM 50           
#define maxseq 512         
#define maxstring 4096 
#define piDIM 513
```

It returns

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: What are the sizes of vectors `string` and `pattern`? In the code you're showing, they're default-constructed (i.e. size 0). The other thing to ensure is that your object lifetimes are correct. (We can't judge that from your code snippets.)

Comment: You might also find that a stack trace of the crash is helpful.

Comment: @pmdj You are right, just edited. They are maxstring and maxseq.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately obvious that's wrong, but there's a lot of code you haven't shared, so there's a good chance the problem lies somewhere there. It looks like you're checking for OpenCL runtime errors, so assuming you're not skipping any of those, the crash dump would be my next thing to look at. Where is it crashing, what memory address, what's near that address? When running your kernel, is it blocking or not? If not, are you sure the lifetimes of your vectors are long enough?

Comment: @pmdj I think that the problem is in the Kernel function, because with the initialisation of the parameters above (the first one) runs and returns the right result. Also if I run it without host code it runs, but then when I change DIM, maxseq, maxstring and piDIM it returns me segmentation fault. How can I do to check the memory address and the lifetimes of the vectors ?

Comment: To clarify: 1. If you run an *empty* kernel function but with the updated dimensions, does it crash? 2. What kind of OpenCL device are you running on? CPU? GPU? 3. For the stack trace and crash address, from the crash message I assume you're on Linux? I suspect the best way there is to load the dumped core into gdb (or run your program in gdb)

Comment: Note that depending on the crash location and depending on OpenCL hardware, the crash address may be meaningless.